# sed command not working with search string

Tags: sed

I have a log file which look like the following

```
2017-05-30 23:11:34,429 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:34,438 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:34,438 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking auth agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:34,453 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - SSH: Failed login attempt on [172.16.8.1]. Username: "rene1".
2017-05-30 23:11:33,673 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking logout agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:33,682 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Logout agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:33,819 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.KeyboardInteractiveAuthentication - SSH: Sent SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_INFO_REQUEST (Password Authentication): 
2017-05-30 23:11:33,871 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - User login attempt has been made from address /172.16.8.1:54626
2017-05-30 23:11:32,042 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:32,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:31,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:31,090 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:31,091 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking auth agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:31,095 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - SSH: Failed login attempt on [172.16.8.1]. Username: "rene1".
2017-05-30 23:11:30,429 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:30,429 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:30,438 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:30,438 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking auth agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:30,453 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - SSH: Failed login attempt on [172.16.8.1]. Username: "rene1".
2017-05-30 23:11:30,429 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:26,429 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:26,438 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:20,438 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking auth agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:20,453 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - SSH: Failed login attempt on [172.16.8.1]. Username: "rene1".
2017-05-30 23:11:18,673 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking logout agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:18,682 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Logout agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:15,819 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.KeyboardInteractiveAuthentication - SSH: Sent SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_INFO_REQUEST (Password Authentication): 
2017-05-30 23:11:15,871 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - User login attempt has been made from address /172.16.8.1:54626
2017-05-30 23:11:14,042 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:14,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:12,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:11,090 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:10,091 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking auth agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:09,095 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - SSH: Failed login attempt on [172.16.8.1]. Username: "rene1".
2017-05-30 23:11:09,415 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - User login attempt has been made from address gateway/172.16.8.1:54626
2017-05-30 23:10:59,416 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:10:42,429 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:10:35,429 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:10:30,438 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
```

I would like to search the log file using `sed` for my starting search string is `Invoking logout agent` until the ending search string is `Failed login attempt`. If match the criteria, it's will return the information between these search strings.So,there might be several matched criteria return since it's might printed somewhere else in the log . But i fail to make it work as expected but it's work with time range where i had used it before. This is my `sed` and required arguments

```
sed -n '/Invoking logout agent/,/Failed login attempt/p' 1min.txt
```

It's seem like return me whole chunk of log file because the first line of returned information don't have "`Invoking logout agent`". From there, i can know that its not working properly.May i know what is my problem? This is the chunk of log that i need the most

```
2017-05-30 23:11:33,673 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking logout agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:33,682 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Logout agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:33,819 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.KeyboardInteractiveAuthentication - SSH: Sent SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_INFO_REQUEST (Password Authentication): 
2017-05-30 23:11:33,871 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - User login attempt has been made from address /172.16.8.1:54626
2017-05-30 23:11:32,042 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:32,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:31,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:31,090 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:31,091 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking auth agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:31,095 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - SSH: Failed login attempt on [172.16.8.1]. Username: "rene1".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***sed*** solution:

```
sed -n '/Invoking logout agent/{:a;N;/Failed login attempt/!ba;G;p;}' imin.txt
```

The output:

```
2017-05-30 23:11:33,673 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking logout agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:33,682 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Logout agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:33,819 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.KeyboardInteractiveAuthentication - SSH: Sent SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_INFO_REQUEST (Password Authentication): 
2017-05-30 23:11:33,871 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - User login attempt has been made from address /172.16.8.1:54626
2017-05-30 23:11:32,042 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:32,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:31,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:31,090 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:31,091 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking auth agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:31,095 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - SSH: Failed login attempt on [172.16.8.1]. Username: "rene1".

2017-05-30 23:11:18,673 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking logout agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:18,682 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Logout agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:15,819 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.KeyboardInteractiveAuthentication - SSH: Sent SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_INFO_REQUEST (Password Authentication): 
2017-05-30 23:11:15,871 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - User login attempt has been made from address /172.16.8.1:54626
2017-05-30 23:11:14,042 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:14,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:12,072 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking config agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:11,090 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Config agent success [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=gateway/172.16.8.1]
2017-05-30 23:11:10,091 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - Invoking auth agent [accountName=rene1 remoteAddress=STEDGE/172.16.8.3]
2017-05-30 23:11:09,095 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - SSH: Failed login attempt on [172.16.8.1]. Username: "rene1".
```

---

***Details***:

- `/Invoking logout agent/` - on each encountering line with `Invoking logout agent`
- `:a;` - define label `a`
- `N;` - append next line to the pattern space
- `/Failed login attempt/!ba;` - unless the pattern space contains `Failed login attempt` - jump back to label `a`
- `G` - append newline after each matched contents for readability
- `p` - print the pattern space